# Laravel sync() with multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have a many-to-many relationship between 2 models in my Laravel application. On this pivot table I store additional information including an array which needs to be converted into json.

The pivot data looks as follows:

```
$pivotData = [
    'name' => 'Normal string',
    'items' => [
        '0' => 'String A',
        '1' => 'String B',
        '2' => 'String C',
    ]
]
```

On my pivot table between ModelA and ModelB I have the 2 columns ('name' and 'items') set up. The **items** column is set up as a json column and casts as such.

Once **$modelA** and **$modelB** is created I want to sync this array with ModelB in the pivot table as follows:

```
$modelA->relationshipMethod()->sync([
    $modelB->getKey() => $pivotData
])
```

When this runs, I get an error `Array to string conversion` in `/opt/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php` which comes from the fact that 'items' is an array.

What am I doing wrong and how should this be handled if your pivot table contains json columns?

Comment: But then it won't know the id of $modelB to which this data belongs to.

Comment: Is $pivotData the model representation of $modelB or is it already created? even thou your question is very well explained it becomes confusing, could you eg. draw up the database tables for the example data and how $pivotData maps to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with `pivot` tables, if there are additional columns, you must declare that in your model file when you create the relationship

```
return $this->belongsToMany(ModelB::class)->withPivot('name', 'items');
```

either only the model keys will be present

and in controller:

```
$pivotData = [
    'name' => 'Normal string',
    'items' => json_encode([
        '0' => 'String A',
        '1' => 'String B',
        '2' => 'String C',
    ])
];

$modelA->modelB()->syncWithPivotValues($modelB->getKey(), $pivotData);
```

you can add an array of ID's of `modelB` in the first param like the example in docs

```
$user->roles()->syncWithPivotValues([1, 2, 3], ['active' => true]);
```

or just you can use sync like:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

you can see more in the [docs link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)

Answer (score 0):

`sync` method doesn't load the `$casts` variable defined on pivot model, then you need to store values as strings:

```php
$pivotData = [
    'name' => 'Normal string',
    'items' => json_encode([
        '0' => 'String A',
        '1' => 'String B',
        '2' => 'String C',
    ])
];

$modelA->relationshipMethod()->sync([
    $modelB->getKey() => $pivotData
]);
```

If you want to use your current Pivot Model, you can change the `ModelA` Model to:

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function relationshipMethod(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ModelB::class, PivotModel::class);
}
```

This only works if your `PivotModel` is extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` instead `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models